# Adding On Delete Restrict references constraint to SQL Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Houses 
(
    size integer PRIMARY KEY,
    description text NOT NULL,
    cost integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (cost) REFERENCES someTable (someColumn)
);
```

How would I add a `On Delete Restrict` references constraint to cost column?

I've tried using `ALTER TABLE` and `ALTER COLUMN` but I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s postgresql

Comment: You should to drop the existing constraint and create the new one. Use `alter table houses drop constraint constraint_name;` and `alter table houses add constraint constraint_name foreign key ...;` for this. To find out the `constraint_name` use `\d houses` command in the `psql`. It could be something like `"houses_cost_fkey"`.

Comment: `on delete restrict` is the default and will be created with the `create table` you have shown

Comment: @Abelisto thank you, i was also able to find the name of the constraint under the SQL pane when looking at all my tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought that the `no action` is default...

Comment: @Abelisto: yes it is, but it is essentially the same thing as `restrict` [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) "*This is the same as NO ACTION except that the check is not deferrable*"